# get greatest Id from multiple table and remove duplicate value

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

i got some problem obtaining value from my db,this is my first db

```
ID_HARGA    ID_USER     ID_BAG_PEMASARAN    ID_ITEM     HARGA   ENTRY_DATE
1             9           1                       3     1000000     2015-01-11 09:55:27
2             9           1                       5     2000000     2015-01-13 07:19:10
5             9           1                       3     3000000     2015-01-13 13:47:32
6             9           1                       43    7000000     2015-01-13 13:49:49
13            9           1                       50    3000000     2015-01-13 17:56:54
37            9           1                       50    100     2015-01-19 09:08:20
```

this is the second one

```
ID_ITEM     NAMA_ITEM            SPEC_ITEM      MASA_GARANSI  STATUS_ITEM     DIR_IMAGE
    3       water heater emas     bagus sekali  selamanya         1      
    5       water heater tembaga  bagus super   selamanya         1      
    43      water hater           heater seupo  3                 1      water_22.jpg
    50      tankkk                50 Liter      1                 1      water_2.jpg
```

i know there is some null value just igniore it, i already did this

```
public function get_item()
{

            //menghitung jumlah varian barang yang ada
            $querycounter = $this->db->query('select * from ITEM WHERE STATUS_ITEM = 1');
            $counter = $querycounter->num_rows();

            $this->db->select('ITEM.ID_ITEM,NAMA_ITEM,SPEC_ITEM,HARGA,DIR_IMAGE');
            $this->db->from('ITEM');
            $this->db->join('HARGA', 'ITEM.ID_ITEM = HARGA.ID_ITEM','left');
            //  $this->db->order_by('ENTRY_DATE','DESC');
            //$this->db->limit($counter);
            $this->db->where('STATUS_ITEM',1);

    //$query = $this->db->query('select  from ITEM i join HARGA h on i.ID_ITEM = h.ID_ITEM order by h.ENTRY_DATE ASC');  


            $query = $this->db->get();
            return $query->result_array();

    //$this->db->select('nama_item','spec_item');
//$query = $this->db->get('item');


}
```

what i want is,just ignore dir_image

```
ID_ITEM     NAMA_ITEM               HARGA       DIR_IMAGE
   3        water heater emas       1000000
   5        water heater tembaga    3000000
  43        water hater             7000000
  50        tankk                   100
```

ID_item with biggest number not the old , so everytime i am insert into id_harga with ID_ITEM

the result always the newest HARGA

Thx before

Answer (score 0):

There is a little confession that, do you want to get the maximum hagra, or newest inserted data (identifiable by HAGRA_ID if its auto increment by 1) in Hagra table. Your Code should be like

```
  $this->db->select('ITEM.ID_ITEM,NAMA_ITEM,SPEC_ITEM,max(HARGA),DIR_IMAGE');
  $this->db->from('ITEM');
  $this->db->join('HARGA', 'ITEM.ID_ITEM = HARGA.ID_ITEM','left');
  $this->db->where('STATUS_ITEM',1);
  $this->db->group_by('item.item_id');
```

This will join your tables and select maximum value of Hagra. To use Max function, you need to use [group_by](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html)*(CodeIgniter Documentation)* clause, other wise it will show only the single maximum value. Group_by will help to show maximum value of each group (each item);

If you want to get the newest inserted data, you can use the same technique using

```
$this->db->select('MAX(HAGRA_ID),ITEM.ID_ITEM,NAMA_ITEM,SPEC_ITEM,HARGA,DIR_IMAGE');
```